# static_cast int to reference to int?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, static-cast

Is it allowed:

```
int x = 1;
int r1 = static_cast<int&>(x);
int r2 = static_cast<int&&>(x)
```

If it is, then what is the meaning of these casts?

The question has arisen from this code:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
std::swap(x, y); // uses int temp = std::move(x);
```

Comment: `static_cast<int&>(x);` does nothing, as is already a lvalue.

Comment: the question is not really clear to me; are you asking for the meaning or for the use cases? What link do you make with the swap?

Comment: moving for int is basially same as copy...

Comment: @Jarod42: Incorrect, see https://rextester.com/KJB49842

Comment: isn't x just a reference to z in that example?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Nice counter example. (as adding extra parenthesis: [`decltype((x))`](https://rextester.com/JIDJ24808) ;-) )

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: No, `x` is definitely not a reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> static_cast int to reference to int?
>   Is it allowed

Yes. It is allowed.

> If it is, then what is the meaning of these casts?

Casting to lvalue reference of same type is mostly pointless, since a variable used by itself is already an lvalue. However, it can affect decltype deduction as shown in [Ben Voigt's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313620/static-cast-int-to-reference-to-int/56313746#comment99237571_56313620). Casting to a reference to another type is useful if you need to downcast a reference to base (which is not relevant to `int`).

Casting to rvalue reference is useful, since it changes the type of the expression into xvalue. This allows moving from variables. This is in fact what `std::move` does. This doesn't make a difference with `int` in particular though.

Comment: Thank you! Got it. I suppose static_cast int to reference to int can even be done explicitly - for example when we return from a class method a reference to a member variable int& X::getSize() { return m_size; } ?

Answer (score 1):

```
static_cast<int&>(x);
```

Doesn't do anything as `x` is already of type `int&` when used in expression.

```
static_cast<int&&>(x);
```

Casts `x`, an l-value, to r-value. This is exactly what `std::move` does and `T&&` are used for implementing move semantics.

`std::swap` uses `std::move` because there's simply no downside and probable performance boost. Move ctors/assignments should always be at least as efficient as copy ctors/assignments.

Comment: "Doesn't do anything" and "x is already of type `int&`" are both false, compare `decltype(x)` to `decltype(static_cast<int&>(x))`  Demonstration: https://rextester.com/KJB49842

Comment: You're confusing types with value categories. `x` is _lvalue_ `int` when used in an expression.